# Persist Drop Down Selection after reload via URL Query Parameter

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am attempting to persist the user selection of a mat-option whenever the page refreshes/reload via URL query parameter.

Upon user selection, the URL will correctly update, and URL will persist w/ query param on reload of page.

> before selection:
> /support/home/devices

> after selection: /support/home/devices?org=HarvardSchool

However, the issue is that the mat-option will revert back to its default value. How can I persist the user selection based off the URL Query Param i.e. mat-option list should be set to value of HarvardSchool as opposed to the default value?

```
  async orgChange(evt: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
      const orgName = evt.option.value.name.replaceAll(' ', '');
      this.currentSelectedOrg.emit(evt.option.value);
      this.orgControl.setValue(evt.option.value);
      this.currentUserOrg.next(evt.option.value);
      void this.router.navigate(['/home/devices'], {
        queryParams: { org: orgName }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're using `router.navigate()` to add `queryParams`, this is making the page to refresh. So the component will rerender and your mat-option will reset to default. To avoid this, you should check inside `OnInit` if the `queryParams` is present and if yes, then set the value to `mat-option`.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.orgControl.setValue(params?.org || 'default');
    })
  }
```

Comment: Added this to `NgOnInit`, and it is setting the right value (queryParam) to the orgControl. However, the issue now is that the input/mat-option control is rendering the placeholder value instead of the queryParam (Harvard School). Selecting an option from the list doesn't actually update the control to render the selected option - just renders the placeholder value

Comment: This is because you are setting `evt.option.value` inside `orgControl`. See line `this.orgControl.setValue(evt.option.value);` while you’re passing `evt.option.value.name` as `orgName` to your route URL. Please make sure you are using correct value both in route and your control.

Comment: Additionally, please share your template code to identify what’s wrong there